# Issues Retrieving Reactions from a Post Using LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am attempting to retrieve reactions from a test post I made on a LinkedIn organization page using LinkedIn's API, and have run into a couple of issues.

According to the API documentation, I should send the following: GET request:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(actor:{encoded personUrn|encoded organizationUrn},entity:{encoded shareUrn|encoded ugcPostUrn|encoded commentUrn})`

However, when I send this request, I receive a 500 Internal Server Error:

> {"message": "Internal Server Error", "status": 500}

So I tried a different request, per the documentation: at this time I received a 400 error with the following message:

> {"message":"input %28entity%3Aurn%3Ali%3Ashare%3AXXXXX%29 is not a Compound key","status":400}

Anybody faced something similar using LinkedIn API and has tips?